# python nested list retrieve and print specific elements

Tags: python, mapreduce

I have a nested list that looks like this. It is supposed to represent people and their possible connections. I need to output the number in quotes along with connections they might know (numbers in the sublist with 2 or 3 after the colon along with a list of people they probably (numbers in the sublist with 4 or more after the colon),so it looks like this:

```
6:Might(1,3,4,7,11)
1:Might(4,6,7) Probably(11)
4:Might(1,3,6,11,12)
```

here is my nested list

```
    connect_cnt =   [(6, {3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 13: 1, 1: 3, 11: 2, 12: 1}),  
       (1, {7: 3, 5: 1, 9: 2, 11: 4, 10: 1 , 2: 1, 13: 1, 3: 2, 6: 3, 4: 3, 12: 2}),                                     
       (4, {3: 2, 7: 3, 6: 3, 13: 1, 1: 3, 11: 2,12: 3, 5: 1, 2: 1, 9: 1}),
```

I am not sure how to go about it. I tried this for starters just to see if I could get the count but it didn't work.

```
     final_dict 
     for row in range(len(connect_cnt)):
        for col in  range(len(connect_cnt[row])):
           key,value = connect_cnt[row].split(':')
           if value > 1:
               final_dict[key] = value
```

Even if I cold just get the ones I need to print in a nested list. I am a beginner and don't have much experience with nested lists.

Comment: Where do the `mapreduce` and `n` tags come in here?

Comment: n was added inadvertantly and I need to run it on mapreduce so it needs to be stateless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact solution to your answer, but I can provide a generalized solution which you can adapt to your needs.

```
l = [(1, {2: 3, 4: 5}), (6, {7: 8, 9: 10})]
# to change a value
l[0][1][2] = 100 # now l = [(1, {2: 100, 4: 5}), (6, {7: 8, 9: 10})]
```

If this does not work for your example, please provide more information, and I will try my best to help out.

Edit:
This code should extract all key-value pairs to another dictionary, given that a dictionary are always the second element of the sub-list.

```
final_dict = {}
for i in l:
    for j in i[1].keys():
        final_dict[j] = i[j]
```

Edit 2:
I think I understand now. This code should do it:

```
for i in l:
    for j in i[1].keys():
        if i[1][j] <= 1:
            del i[1][j]
```

Edit 3:
Sorry. Let me know if this works:

```
l2 = []
for i in l:
    d = {}
    for j in i[1].keys():
        if i[1][j] > 1:
           d[j] = i[1][j]
    l2.append((i[0], d))
```

Comment: Sure what I would like to do is to pull out all key value pairs of the dict where the number after the colon is greater than 1. I did a horrible job explaining it up top. My apologies.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if I understood the problem.

Comment: I just need to extract the ones where the number after the colon is greater than 1. So for 6 it would look like this [6{1: 3, 3:3,4:3,7: 2,11:2) and for  1 it would be like this     [1 {4:3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 11: 4})

Comment: I think I understood the problem. Let me know if the code works.

Comment: I got an error RuntimeError: Dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Edit 3 should work. I ran it on my own IDE, and it ran correctly.

Comment: yes that worked thank you so much. I need a lot of work figuring out iteration logic